# Multiple column index and single column index

Tags: mysql, indexing

In mysql indexing

Case 1 :

```
   Created the index for two column, but used only one column in where clause.
```

Will it use index?

Case 2:

```
  Created the index for single column, but used index created column and 
  non-indexed column in where clause.
```

Will it use index?

How the indexing work in multiple column index? How the indexing work in where clause.?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a good explanation of how composite indexes are used in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

For your question.

If your index is `table(col1, col2)`, then the index would normally be used for `where` conditions on `col1` but not on `col2`.

```
This includes both equality and inequality conditions.  It would not be used if `col1` is 
wrapped in a function.

For the second case, the index would normally be used for the condition where it could be 
used. For the second condition, the database engine would look up the records in the table 
and apply the second condition directly on the data.
```

There are some cases where using an index would not be faster than just scanning the table.  For instance, on a small table (just a few rows) scanning the table is often faster.  Similarly, if the index is fetching a large'ish number of rows in the table, it might be faster to do a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql documentation seems pretty clear on this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/mysql-indexes.html

So, in short:

Case 1 - it depends if you use the left-most column in the index, in your where statement, or not.

Case 2 - Yes, the index will be used, assuming there are no other indexes that return fewer rows